# Count occurrences in several xml-files

Tags: python, xml

Is there a way to count all occurrences of identity of a certain type over several xml-files?
Here's an example what I mean. All xml-files have the following structure:

```
<data>
  <geo>
    <g type="mount" stid="s727" level="geo"/>
    <g type="bike" stid="g12" level="geo"/>
    <g type="lake" stid="g12432" level="geo"/>
    <g type="mount" stid="s0" level="geo"/>
  </geo>
</data>
```

What I'd like to count is the number of occurences of "s0", "s"+any number, "s12" PER TYPE and the same 3 categories for the g's.
Can someone show me how this would work? Of course, it would last to have as example only on category - what is important to me is how you save the intermediate results and how you would do the main-function (I suppose you'll do it with sys.arg - at least, this is what I would do...)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can [have a look at LXML](http://lxml.de/) to parse XML file

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the LXML library for this type of thing. It's very well documented.
Here is a little script I wrote which is kind of what I think you want. If you only care about the count and not the items, you could increment a value instead of appending to a list. Also, this only gets attributes which contain s, but can easily be modified to get values which begin with s if that is what you are going for.

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

parser = etree.XMLParser()
FileInstance = open('help1.xml', 'r')
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(FileInstance.read()), parser)
FileInstance.close()

output = []

for i in tree.xpath('//geo'):
    for element in i:
        if "s" in element.attrib['stid']:
            output.append(element.attrib['stid'])

print output
print len(output)
```